# Disable Product Display upon purchase of the Product or it's variations

Tags: rules, commerce

I have a site of products wherein each *Product Display* has 2 *Variations* (*Products*).

I would like it so when a single variation is purchased the Product Display get's unpublished (regardless of a variation still being available for purchase).

I've been trying to do this with **Rules** with little success, has anyone come across this before or know of a solid solution?

Answer (score 0):

The [Disable product when it was purchased](http://drupal.org/node/1252002) issue on d.o. deals exactly with this problem.